# No image is storage on Drupal 7 for user profile

Tags: drupal-7, image-uploading, user-profile

I want to upload the user picture profile in Drupal 7.x but there are some problems when I click on save button on the user profile. After I did it, no file was saved in the default directory and no URL was created

I have overwritten the template file "user-profile-edit.tpl.php" where I create my personal theme. Also before, I add on template.php the code to allow override theme.

```
       $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MyTheme') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'user-profile-edit',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

in "edit-profile-edit.tpl.php" I have this

```
print render($form['picture']['picture_current']);
print render($form['picture']['picture_upload']);
print render($form['picture']['picture_delete']);

$account = user_load(arg(1));
$profile_image= file_create_url($account->picture->uri);

print_r ($user);
print theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user));
```

When I change the Name or password and save, all the informations are submitted and saved but when I try to upload the image, no image is stored on directory default Drupal and no path image was built.

I activated user to upload it on Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings.

Can someone help me? What I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I FIXED the problem. The problem was in URL. I was in [link]sitename/?q=usermbm/ID/edit/main. This was the problem. In this URL Drupal form have the fields password and confirm password but are different from the form in URL [link]sitename/?q=usermbm/ID/edit. If I want to change the password and upload the image the exact URL is just [link]sitename/?q=usermbm/ID/edit not edit/main where we can see all the other information about the user profile